# How can I "wrap" a square image around a sphere

Tags: java, image

This might sound odd, but I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to do. So I have a square (128x128) image which I would like to rescale as if it were mapped onto a sphere of radius 64, so that if I had an image that were just a grid, it would look this after the scaling as been done: http://www.cartographersguild.com/attachments/virtual-tabletop-battlemap-mapping/42871d1331205337-representing-sphere-battlemap-sphere7.jpg . I've looked around the web, but there are just so many terms for various kinds of spherical mapping that it's overwhelming me, and I would like to pick the best option. Most of what I have seen seems to pertain to 3D spheres, but I am only interested in a 2D operation.

Comment: Have you tried googling "fish lens equations"? Is that the effect you're going for?

Comment: Do you need the image to go "all around" the sphere, i.e. should part of it be hidden due to being on the back side of the sphere? Or would you like

Comment: I'm really not sure, all I know is that the picture needs to be warped. I guess a great way to describe it would be to take a blanket and drape it over a big ball and look at it from the top down. I suppose that the corners won't be hidden, just scaled down gradually into nothing.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, dont you need a rectangle to wrap a sphere? The length should be the dia of the spherical circle.